# gapi is not defined - Google sign in issue with gapi.auth2.init

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign In and retrieve the profile information of the user. 
The error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined. Why is that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'filler_text_for_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });
    });
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It happens because you have `async` and `defer` attributes on your script tag. `gapi` would be loaded after your script tag with `gapi.auth2.init`...

To wait for `gapi` before executing this code you can use onload query param in script tag, like following:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
<script>
window.onLoadCallback = function(){
  gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'filler_text_for_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });
}
</script>
```

Or for case when you need it in many places, you can use promises to better structure it:

```
// promise that would be resolved when gapi would be loaded
var gapiPromise = (function(){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  window.onLoadCallback = function(){
    deferred.resolve(gapi);
  };
  return deferred.promise()
}());

var authInited = gapiPromise.then(function(){
  gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'filler_text_for_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });
})


$('#btn').click(function(){
  gapiPromise.then(function(){
    // will be executed after gapi is loaded
  });

  authInited.then(function(){
    // will be executed after gapi is loaded, and gapi.auth2.init was called
  });
});
```

Comment: where should I add the onSignOut function then? It also requires gapi, but I only call it when the user clicks on the button

Comment: you can add it to `onLoadCallback` too, e.g place `$(function(){ .... })` there..

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Sorry I didn't mention it before. Trying to call signOut results in a "Uncaught ReferenceError: signOut is not defined"

Comment: OH wait, nevermind. you're talking about the document.ready function lol. wait a second, let me try it.

Comment: added example how to structure this with promises

Comment: I did all this, and even added a interval to check if it's loaded, but still had problems. Finally I removed the async in the script tag and since that it seems to work.

Comment: the first one worked for me, I just get this error (I'm using Angular2) ```zone.js:1235 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: onLoadCallback```

Comment: This did not work for me. Anyone looking for a solution that works if you're using Vue with a separate log out component, refer to @bora89's answer below.

Answer (score 19):

I think you'll find with the above example that this won't work either, as `gapi.auth2` will not yet be defined (I know this because I made the same mistake myself, today) You first need to call `gapi.load('auth2', callback)` and pass THAT a callback which then calls `gapi.auth2.init`. Here is an example of my `_onGoogleLoad` function, which is the callback for loading the first `platform.js` script.

```
var _auth2

var _onGoogleLoad = function () {
  gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    _auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'OUR_REAL_ID_GOES_HERE',
      scope: 'email',
      fetch_basic_profile: false
    })
    _enableGoogleButton()
  })
}
```

After that, you can use the `_auth2` variable to actually sign users in.

Comment: OR you include a `<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>` (etc..) button as described in the docs. When present, platform.js will automatically download `auth2`. This seems to trigger the exact same content being downloaded. The documentation is not very good in this regard, unfortunately. Also, the `<script>` in index.html can be `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` instead of `platform.js` in your case, which contains a little less code.

Comment: @phil294 is there a way to suppress that behaviour ?

Comment: @beppe9000 I dont know, sorry

Answer (score 18):

The problem is not only in `gapi`. To call `init` method - auth2 object must be initialized.
There is a promise once a google auth object is in fully initialized [`GoogleAuth.then(onInit, onFailure)`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenwzxhzdk60oninitwzxhzdk61_wzxhzdk62onfailurewzxhzdk63)

```
gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);

function initSigninV2() {
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    }).then(function (authInstance) {
        // now auth2 is fully initialized
    });
}
```

Comment: All i needed was this

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! If you're using Vue.js and you're using a separate component for logging out, this works!

Comment: You saved my day! This is the right answer. Thanks. Long Live!

Answer (score 6):

While these answers helped me, I believe there is better answer in official docs.

See [Integrating Google Sign-In using listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners)

```
var auth2; // The Sign-In object.
var googleUser; // The current user.

/**
 * Calls startAuth after Sign in V2 finishes setting up.
 */
var appStart = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
};

/**
 * Initializes Signin v2 and sets up listeners.
 */
var initSigninV2 = function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Listen for sign-in state changes.
  auth2.isSignedIn.listen(signinChanged);

  // Listen for changes to current user.
  auth2.currentUser.listen(userChanged);

  // Sign in the user if they are currently signed in.
  if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
    auth2.signIn();
  }

  // Start with the current live values.
  refreshValues();
};

/**
 * Listener method for sign-out live value.
 *
 * @param {boolean} val the updated signed out state.
 */
var signinChanged = function (val) {
  console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
  document.getElementById('signed-in-cell').innerText = val;
};

/**
 * Listener method for when the user changes.
 *
 * @param {GoogleUser} user the updated user.
 */
var userChanged = function (user) {
  console.log('User now: ', user);
  googleUser = user;
  updateGoogleUser();
  document.getElementById('curr-user-cell').innerText =
    JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2);
};

/**
 * Updates the properties in the Google User table using the current user.
 */
var updateGoogleUser = function () {
  if (googleUser) {
    document.getElementById('user-id').innerText = googleUser.getId();
    document.getElementById('user-scopes').innerText =
      googleUser.getGrantedScopes();
    document.getElementById('auth-response').innerText =
      JSON.stringify(googleUser.getAuthResponse(), undefined, 2);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('user-id').innerText = '--';
    document.getElementById('user-scopes').innerText = '--';
    document.getElementById('auth-response').innerText = '--';
  }
};

/**
 * Retrieves the current user and signed in states from the GoogleAuth
 * object.
 */
var refreshValues = function() {
  if (auth2){
    console.log('Refreshing values...');

    googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();

    document.getElementById('curr-user-cell').innerText =
      JSON.stringify(googleUser, undefined, 2);
    document.getElementById('signed-in-cell').innerText =
      auth2.isSignedIn.get();

    updateGoogleUser();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### For a Vue.JS app

- Add an onload hook to the script tag for `platform.js`
- Set up a function that dispatches an event
- Catch that event in the `mounted` hook of your component.

Here's a fairly complete example you can just paste into a new `vue-cli` project.

Don't forget to supply your own client ID!

#### public/index.html

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function triggerGoogleLoaded() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("google-loaded"));
      }
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleLoaded"
      async
      defer
    ></script>
    <meta
      name="google-signin-client_id"
      content="xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    />
```

#### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="google-signin-btn"></div>
      <a href="#" class="sign-out" @click="signOut" v-if="profile">Sign out</a>
    </div>
    <div v-if="profile" class="">
      <h2>Signed In User Profile</h2>
      <pre>{{ profile }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!profile">
      <h2>Signed out.</h2>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      profile: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSignIn(user) {
      const profile = user.getBasicProfile();
      this.profile = profile;
    },
    signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(() => {
        location.reload(true);
      });
    },
    renderGoogleLoginButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render("google-signin-btn", {
        onsuccess: this.onSignIn
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("google-loaded", this.renderGoogleLoginButton);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314602/1034622

Include this script tag

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: This has the minified version:

`<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'></script>`

Answer (score -3):

Cheap Fix is:
To tell Eslint that this is a global variable by using
`/* global gapi */`

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with eslint, and the error isn't coming from eslint; it's a JavaScript runtime error.