# ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api-js-client

SO i am new at this what i am trying to do is using Angular as Front-end to make a simple button that when clicked asks for user to Authenticate just like any login using gmail example but i keep getting this error and here is my code what i am trying to do is use the code provided by google 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
and covert it to typescript

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  async authenticate() {
    return await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    });
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <button class="signup" (click)="authenticate()">authorize and load</button>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the Google platform API script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Include this script tag

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: still getting the same error     core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
Refe

Comment: Did you include in index.html

Comment: ok it worked but i raised a new error   core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846232/how-to-implement-signin-with-google-in-angular-2-using-typescript  go through this answer and try to implement

Comment: This has the minified version:

`<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'></script>`