# application sign-on issues using angular-google-gapi and Google platform.js script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cloud-platform

Our application is deployed on GCP (Google Cloud). It uses Google based authentication. Recently since 25th Feb 22 , we have been observing sign in issues in the application.
When we hit the developer console on chrome , we see an error
": bundle.js:17014 Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setApiKey')"

The error line then points to below api :

- An AngularJS module for use all Google Apis and your Google Cloud Endpoints

  - @version 1.0.0-beta.2
  - @link https://github.com/maximepvrt/angular-google-gapi

This api is further calling Google platform.js script which opens the Google sign in page (the user puts his/her email and then they log in to app post authentication).

This issue is intermittent e.g. it happens for 20 mins and then we clear the cache and cookies and then it goes away but then it comes back again. This workaround does not even work in all attempts and hit and trail works. Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: You may have a look at a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314208/referenceerror-gapi-is-not-defined).

Comment: did you find any solution, we also seem to have the same problem. we investigated it a little, check our findings https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/797