# I can't login with googleAuth with React, Ionic, Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to create a login with google.
I work with React, Ionic, Capacitor.
I followed all the steps from:
https://enappd.com/blog/google-login-in-ionic-react-capacitor-apps/122/

and I have this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
>      at GoogleAuthWeb._callee$

Did someone had this issue and solved it?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144874/gapi-is-not-defined-google-sign-in-issue-with-gapi-auth2-init