How can I get my code to make a table that displays information from a google sheets document using API Key?
I am trying to use Google Sheets to make a leaderboard table in my website, it is for a university project that I am making that displays an esports leaderboard system, with the use of js.
    <!-- HTML for Leaderboard -->
  <div id="leaderboard">
    <h2>Esports Leaderboard</h2>
    <ul id="leaderboard-list">
      <script src="js/leaderboard.js"></script>
      <!-- Leaderboard items will be inserted here dynamically using JavaScript -->
    </ul>
  </div>

Here is the HTML for it, it is an empty ul that has been given CSS properties, and I want the leaderboard to be dynamically inputed through the use of my script.
#leaderboard {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#leaderboard h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#leaderboard ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#leaderboard li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#leaderboard li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

#leaderboard .username {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

Lastly, here is the script that I am using, I have put my API key in there, and the relevant sheetsID and the range is set for where the data that needs retrieving is set.
// Function to load Google Sheets API
function loadSheetsAPI() {
  gapi.load('client', function() {
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'key'
    }).then(function() {
      fetchData();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error initializing Google Sheets API:', error);
    });
  });
}

// Load Google Sheets API with a delay
setTimeout(loadSheetsAPI, 1000); // Adjust the delay time as needed (in milliseconds)


// Function to fetch data from Google Sheets
function fetchData() {
  if (!gapi.client.sheets) {
    console.error('Google Sheets API is not loaded or initialized.');
    return;
  }

  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1HWGVLLX1ugAewLUMAyLxImHo_qeBzam5-Z8RzBpxVBI',
    range: 'Sheet1!A1:C21' // Change this to match the range you want to fetch
  }).then(function(response) {
    var range = response.result;
    if (range.values && range.values.length > 0) {
      displayData(range.values);
    } else {
      console.log('No data found in the specified range.');
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data from Google Sheets:', error);
  });
}

// Function to display data in HTML
function displayData(data) {
  var leaderboardDiv = document.getElementById('leaderboard');
  var leaderboardList = document.getElementById('leaderboard-list');

  leaderboardDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>Leaderboard</h2>';
  leaderboardList.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = data[i].join(' | ');
    leaderboardList.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}

// Load Google Sheets API
loadSheetsAPI();


However, nothing is working, every change I try, it still does not display within the website, and I am running on a tight deadline, as it is not going live as it's just for a university project, I was trying to get this completed with front end code alone.

Do you get a return error from your fetchData function in console? Are you able to console log your response from API at all in your console?

@dalelandry
leaderboard.js:21 Google Sheets API is not loaded or initialized.
fetchData @ leaderboard.js:21
this is my return error that I am getting from it if this helps at all?

Take a look at this Stackoverflow question and answer. I think it might give you a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144874/gapi-is-not-defined-google-sign-in-issue-with-gapi-auth2-init
